# Why isn't there any indentation?

Tags: punctuation

> It was the best evening of Harry’s life, better than winning at
>   Quidditch, or Christmas, or knocking out mountain trolls… he would
>   never, ever forget tonight.
>
> Harry had almost forgotten that the exam results were still to come,
>   but come they did. To their great surprise, both he and Ron passed
>   with good marks; Hermione, of course, had the best grades of the first
>   years. Even Neville scraped through, his good Herbology mark making up
>   for his abysmal Potions one. They had hoped that Goyle, who was almost
>   as stupid as he was mean, might be thrown out, but he had passed, too.
>   It was a shame, but as Ron said, you couldn’t have everything in
>   life.
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

There is no indentation, a space at the beginning of the second paragraph. Though there is a line skip between the first and second paragraph, why isn’t there the space in the second one. (I checked the British original, Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone, to find it also has no space at the beginning.)

Comment: Note that you can force SE to display a space with the &nbsp; literal--I arbitrarily put two at the beginning of your first paragraph. ... I suspect the blank line and omission of indentation (which also occurs at the beginning of chapters) is intended to mark the end of an episode and passage of time before the next episode begins. This is more strongly marked in print, where the convention is to indent successive paragraphs without a blank line, so a blank line stands out on the page.

Comment: Or you can use full-width spaces, like these: `　　　　　　　`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% necessary to have indentation at the beginning of a new paragraph (It's possibly dying)

Some people will argue about it but it's still not *needed*.